# How to go product details page from product page

Tags: php, database

I'm trying with a E-Commerce website. But I'm having trouble. I want that when I click in the view details link of a product, the details of the product will be shown on the `product_details.php` page. But I can't transfer the product id to the `product_details.php` page. 
My code is here...

```
<?php
  include ("include/header.php");
?>

<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("problem with Connection");
mysql_select_db("finalproject");

$per_page = 3;
$pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('product_id') FROM product");
$pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);

$page = (isset ($_GET['page'])) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;
$start = ($page - 1 ) * $per_page;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product LIMIT $start,$per_page");

while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{ 
    echo "<b>$query_row[product_name]</b><br>";
    echo "<b>Brand : </b> $query_row[product_brand] <br>";
    echo "<b>Description : </b> $query_row[description] <br>";;
    echo "<b>Price : </b> $query_row[price] <br>";
    echo ('<a href="product_details.php?         id='.$query_row['product_id'].'">View details</a><br><br>') ;
?>
<form action="product_details.php?productId=<?php echo $row['product_id'];?    >>" method="post">

<?php
}
$prev = $page - 1;
$next = $page + 1;

if (!($page <=1))
{
    echo "<a href='buyproduct.php?page=$prev'>Prev</a> ";
}

if($pages >= 1)
{
    for ($x=1; $x<=$pages; $x++)
    { 
        echo ($x == $page) ? '<b><a href="?page='.$x.' ">'.$x.'</a></b> ' :  '<a href="?page='.$x.' ">'.$x.'</a> ';
    }
}

if (!($page >= $pages))
{
    echo "<a href='buyproduct.php?page=$next'>Next</a> ";
}
?>

<?php
    include ("include/footer.php");
?>
```

and my `product_details.php` is

```
<?php
    include ("include/header.php");
?>

<?php
include ("database.php");
$productId = $_GET['productId'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id = $productId";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<b>$row[product_name]</b><br>";
    echo "<b>Brand : </b> $row[product_brand] <br>";
    echo "<b>Description : </b> $row[description] <br>";;
    echo "<b>Price : </b> $row[price] <br><br>";
    "<br>"; 
}
?>

<?php
    include ("include/footer.php");
?>
```

and when running in the browser when clicking to viw details in `product_details.php` the error is  :

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\project2\product_details.php on line 17

Now what can I do....

Comment: Are you getting value within `$productId`

Comment: dont use mysql. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php Advice: This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: Please do yourself a favor and [stop using mysql_*](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In product_details.php the syntax of sql query is incorrect. Put $productId in quote.

The query sholu look like this..

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id = '$productId'";
```

Hope this will help..

Comment: Yes, it does some change. the error is not showing no more. But the product_details.php page is not showing Product name, brand, description , price. Rather it is empty.

Comment: try this..                                                                                                   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<b>".$row[product_name]."</b><br>";
    echo "<b>Brand : </b>". $row[product_brand]." <br>";
    echo "<b>Description : </b>". $row[description]." <br>";;
    echo "<b>Price : </b>". $row[price] ."<br><br>";
}

Comment: Check if the product id is passing correctly or not. Just  echo the product id. And check if everything is okay or not.

Comment: There could be another mistake i think.. you have used "id" to pass the product id.. but in the product_details.php you have used          $productId = $_GET['productId']; this should be                            $productId = $_GET['id'];

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your html...

```html
<form action="product_details.php?productId=<?php echo $row['product_id'];?    >>" method="post">
```

Should be...

```html
<form action="product_details.php?productId=<?php echo $row['product_id'];?>" method="post">
```

Your sending an extra ">" with your product id

Comment: I've tried this . But still not working . Showing the same error.

Comment: Can you echo out the query that failed?